# Calculating a variable inside RDD after full outer join in Scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

What I want to do is simpl, but I struggle with Scala and RDDs.
The concept is this:

```
   rdd1                           rdd2

id   count                      id   count            
 a     2                         a     1
 b     1                         c     5
                                 d     3
```

And the result I am searching for is this:

```
  rdd2

id   count                               
 a     3                         
 b     1
 c     5
 d     3
```

what I intend to do is to perform a full outer join to get common and non common registers, identified by the id field. For now, rdd2, is empty. 
rdd1 and rdd2 are:

```
RDD[(String, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)]
```

For now, I have the following code:

```
 var rdd3 = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map {
     case (id, left, right) =>
     // TODO  
 }
```

How can I calculate that sum between RDDs?

Comment: left.count + right.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a `fullOuterJoin` you get the key and two Options passed into the closure (one Option represents the left side, the other one the right side). So the closure could look like this:

```
val result = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map {
  case (id, (left, right)) =>
    (id, left.getOrElse(0) + right.getOrElse(0))
}
```

This applies if your `RDD` is of type `(String, Int)`.

Comment: And, in this case, when there is an unmatched id, its value is replace by 0, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. All three cases are handled by that expression. And if there is no record on one side, zero is added instead.

Comment: This works but, for example, if I execute again the same lines, I expect to have in result, the acumulated countings. Can it be that, as it was executed before, doesn't take into account the new execution and throws the first calculation again?

Comment: The snippet just contains a *transformation* (`filter`,  `map`, ...). It describes the calculation, but it does not really calculate (and does not store the results). You can cache it using `RDD.cache()`, if you need the result more than one time. Only *actions* (like `collect`) trigger the calculation.

Comment: Even if the calculations are made on diferent executions of a script? The idea is run a script (.scala from the spark-shell) every hour, and then calculate this variables.

Comment: The storage level of `cache()` is `MEMORY_ONLY`. There are other options, but this is really another question. Do you need any more help regarding the full outer join topic?